# Reflections in Water

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Take a string as input. This string can be as long as you'd like, however, it may only include letters and spaces––no numbers, punctuation, etc. When a word is passed into your function, an image will be made out of it. This image is the input word written out using only these characters: **–**, **/**, **\**, and **|**. You do not need to use all of these characters, but you may not use any others. **Only words are inputed; no numbers or any other characters.**

Here are a couple examples:

```
Input : "String"

Return : 

 –––    –––    –––   –––  |\    |   –––
|        |    |   |   |   | \   |  |
 –––     |    |–––    |   |  \  |  | ––
    |    |    |   \   |   |   \ |  |   |
 –––     |    |    \ –––  |    \|   –––     //uppercase string written out
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––    //bar
                                            //line break
 –––     |    |    / –––  |    /|   –––
    |    |    |   /   |   |   / |  |   |
 –––     |    |–––    |   |  /  |  | ––
|        |    |   |   |   | /   |  |
 –––    –––    –––   –––  |/    |   –––     //uppercase string written upside-down (reflected)
```

After the all caps string written out, there is a bar and then a line break. After that, there is the same string, just mirrored/upside-down. The bar under the word spelled out should be the length of the written out string. The upside down word––the reflection––goes one line beneath the line break.

Here is another example:

```
Input : "hi"

Return : 

|  |  –––
|  |   |
|––|   |
|  |   |
|  |  –––
–––––––––

|  |  –––
|  |   |
|––|   |
|  |   |
|  |  -––
```

### A bonus challenge/addition:

Add a ripple effect. Have something like a random indent between 0 and 3 spaces before each line in the reflection. Here's an example of what it could look like:

```
Input : "hi"

Return : 

|  |  –––
|  |   |
|––|   |
|  |   |
|  |  –––
–––––––––

 |  |  –––
 |  |   |
  |––|   |
 |  |   |
  |  |  -––
```

### Your code should be in the following form:

```
function createAwesomeness(string) -> string {
    let s = //your code that creates the 'image'
    return s
}

print createAwesomeness("string")
print createAwesomeness("bananas")
```

### A couple notes:

- Every language is valid
- Suggestion: Do not copy the font-set as a dictionary or array because that adds a lot to your code's size. Both as a challenge and to lower your code's size, try to use a function of sorts to create the letters
- Along with your code, have:

  - The size in bytes **of your function**
  - The number of characters **of your function**
  - The two examples
- Shortest, working code wins
- There is currently no deadline

If any further explanation is needed, please tell me in the comments!

Any response is welcome and greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please show the complete fontset that we are supposed to use in this challange?

Comment: @Loovjo – You mean the characters, yes?

Comment: Yes, all the characters.

Comment: Anyway, instead of showing how the answer should be in a function, I would suggest just saying "You should create a function named createAwesomeness that takes the string as the only argument" or something similar.

Comment: @Loovjo - My only hesitation connected to writing font-set is that part of the challenge was writing the letters using the specific characters, not just plugging in prewritten shapes

Comment: So you're saying that the code can use any shape of characters as long as the characters looks like the Input? If so, you might want to specify that.

Comment: @Loovjo - I said that the words should be "written out using these characters: **–**, **/**, **\**, and **|**" and that "each letter should be five characters in height. The width does not matter but it should a) be uniform wherever that same letter appears and b) should be in proportion to the height so that it resembles the letter."

Comment: @Loovjo - Whoops, part of my comment was poorly reformatted; The words should be "written out using these characters: **-**, **/**, <b>\</b>, and <b>|</b>"

Comment: Okay. Will the Input only consist of letters? Or both letters and numbers? All printable ascii characters? You should specify that in the question.

Comment: @Loovjo - OK. I specified in the beginning

Comment: Are letter representations for "S", "T", "R", "I", "N" and "G" other than the ones shown above also valid, or are the ones from above a fixed part of the font set to be used?

Comment: @Chiru - Yes. As I said in the instructions: All letter representations are valid provided that a) they are 5 characters high, and that b) they reasonably resemble the letter.

Comment: @Chiru - Sorry––Yes, they can be in the font-set but no, they do not have to.

Comment: Thanks. Two more questions though: (1) Must **all** of the characters -, /, \, and | be used in the alphabet? (2) Does the input contain one word only or could it also contain more than one word (separated by a space character)?

Comment: @Chiru - Thanks for asking. (1) No. The only thing is that you can only use those four characters. No others. (2) The input can be as long as you'd like, just that it can only have letters and spaces––No numbers or other characters.

Comment: In order to avoid disputes over whether letter representations "*reasonably resemble*" the letter, you should mandate specific representations. (That's also probably the only way you'll get letter representations which use more than one character). With respect to the deadline: deadlines are a Bad Thing™. By all means wait a week before awarding the accepted answer, but a) there's no need to say that you will do that; b) if someone comes along later with a better answer, accept that one instead.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - (a) There is now no deadline (b) I did mandate that letters must be at least 5 chars in height. The width simply has to be proportionate to the height. The letter is valid if it follows those two size criteria and if it is obvious which letter it represents.

Comment: I'm voting to close as *unclear what you're asking*, since, without predefined ASCII art representations of all characters, there's no objective way to determine if a given submission is valid or not. A code golf competition like this one needs a tight specification. Otherwise, the shortest answer is just the one that generates the ugliest font.

Comment: @Dennis - I must disagree with you and I have my evidence.  Chiru has successfully answered my question. He has followed my criteria: 5 characters in height, a proportional width. He has also followed the second piece of criteria, that states that he can only use these characters: / \ - | . He has chosen to use - .

Comment: @Dennis - The only reason that I am not writing my own font-set for you all to use is that *that is part of the challenge*. Chiru has successfully overcome that challenge quite intelligently. Now all he has to do is start thinning it.

Comment: @Dopapp Has he? One could argue that his **B**, **J**, **M**, **Q** and **W** don't look like the letters should. I'm not saying his answer is invalid, but it's certainly debatable. My point is that an answer's validity shouldn't be debatable.

Comment: @Dennis - If I were to add a character set, the challenge would just be who can append characters with the least characters/bytes. That would be fairly boring/simple I think.

Comment: @Dennis I've just edited my solution to make the letter **B** (for starters) look as it should while still keeping the code at its length. I did indeed find it challenging enough to create an "optimal" alphabet for this purpose, and I'd love to see other alphabets and approaches than my own.

Comment: @Dopapp The issue with this question might be resolved if the **community** decides whose code wins, since their votes will criticize the letters' readability but reward proper esthetics, both letter- and program-wise. Readability is, by person, subjective, but if measured in a large enough set of people, becomes quite a reliable metric.

Comment: @Chiru So, you're saying it should be a [tag:popularity-contest]?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yes, that's the word I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This would make a poor popcon (it would be an art contest) and should not be a [tag:code-golf] without a truly objective way to determine if an answer is valid.

Comment: popcon and code-golf are mutually exclusive winning criteria, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) (580 characters/bytes)

Probably not the best/shortest way to do this, but here's my two cents' worth:

```
a=x=>{l=["#####","#   #","#","  #","    #","# #","#  ##","####",""],g=[0,1,1],t=[8,8,8,8,8,0,1,...g,7,1,0,1,7,0,2,2,2,0,7,1,1,1,7,0,2,0,2,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,1,...g,...g,0,3,3,3,0,0,4,4,4,...g,5,5,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,...g,1,1,1,1,6,1,...g,1,0,0,1,0,2,2,...g,6,0,0,1,0,5,1,0,2,0,4,0,0,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,...g,1,1,3,1,1,1,0,...g,3,1,1,1,1,0,3,3,0,4,0,2,0],s=(n,r)=>l[t[5*n+r]].padRight(8),y=Array(10).fill("");for(r=-1,z=0;++r<5&z<x.length;r==4&&++z?r=-1:0){c=x[z].charCodeAt()&31;y[r]+=s(c,r),y[9-r]+=s(c,r)}return`${y.slice(0,5).join`
`}
${"-".repeat(y[0].length-3)}

${y.slice(5).join`
`}`}
console.log(a("string"))
console.log(a("bananas"))
```

Note that although this is [standard ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), this strictly requires sloppy mode (heh, get it?) which hasn't landed in all of the JS engines/transpilers yet; it'll probably be ready this winter. If anyone knows a way to run this code in a sloppy environment as of today, feel free to edit.

Well, since people still need to reproduce my output, I'll just give you the strict version that only differs in the way that it uses "let" to declare variables instead of making them globals by omitting it. Feel free to verify that I only added "let" in four places and changed nothing further. Here's the strict version that you can run today already using [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl):

```js
let a=x=>{let l=["#####","#   #","#","  #","    #","# #","#  ##","####",""],g=[0,1,1],t=[8,8,8,8,8,0,1,...g,7,1,0,1,7,0,2,2,2,0,7,1,1,1,7,0,2,0,2,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,1,...g,...g,0,3,3,3,0,0,4,4,4,...g,5,5,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,...g,1,1,1,1,6,1,...g,1,0,0,1,0,2,2,...g,6,0,0,1,0,5,1,0,2,0,4,0,0,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,...g,1,1,3,1,1,1,0,...g,3,1,1,1,1,0,3,3,0,4,0,2,0],s=(n,r)=>l[t[5*n+r]].rpad(8),y=Array(10).fill("");for(let r=-1,z=0;++r<5&z<x.length;r==4&&++z?r=-1:0){let c=x[z].charCodeAt()&31;y[r]+=s(c,r),y[9-r]+=s(c,r)}return`${y.slice(0,5).join`
`}
${"-".repeat(y[0].length-3)}

${y.slice(5).join`
`}`}
console.log(a("string"))
console.log(a("bananas"))
```

### Output

The first console.log yields **STRING**:

```
#####   #####   #####   #####   #   #   #####   
#         #     #   #     #     #   #   #       
#####     #     #####     #     #   #   #####   
    #     #     # #       #     #  ##   #   #   
#####     #     #   #   #####   #   #   #####   
---------------------------------------------

#####     #     #   #   #####   #   #   #####   
    #     #     # #       #     #  ##   #   #   
#####     #     #####     #     #   #   #####   
#         #     #   #     #     #   #   #       
#####   #####   #####   #####   #   #   #####
```

and the second console.log yields **BANANAS**:

```
####    #####   #   #   #####   #   #   #####   #####   
#   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #       
#####   #####   #   #   #####   #   #   #####   #####   
#   #   #   #   #  ##   #   #   #  ##   #   #       #   
####    #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #####   
-----------------------------------------------------

####    #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #####   
#   #   #   #   #  ##   #   #   #  ##   #   #       #   
#####   #####   #   #   #####   #   #   #####   #####   
#   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #       
####    #####   #   #   #####   #   #   #####   #####
```

### How it works:

My idea was to generate the the alphabet by compressing letters with respect to similar lines. Thus, every letter in the alphabet can be represented as a 5-dimensional vector of numbers that correspond to a string that again corresponds to a row in a letter.

This approach is made a lot easier when every letter has the same width, as this enables us to re-use some string patterns more effectively. With this idea in mind, I then designed a font that is optimized for similar-looking lines in letters, so that it compresses well:

```
#####
#   #
#####
#   #
#   #

#### 
#   #
#####
#   #
#### 

#####
#    
#    
#    
#####

#### 
#   #
#   #
#   #
#### 

#####
#    
#####
#    
#####

#####
#    
#####
#    
#    

#####
#    
#####
#   #
#####

#   #
#   #
#####
#   #
#   #

#####
  #  
  #  
  #  
#####

#####
    #
    #
    #
#####

#   #
#   #
# #  
# #  
#   #

#    
#    
#    
#    
#####

#####
#####
#   #
#   #
#   #

#   #
#   #
#   #
#  ##
#   #

#####
#   #
#   #
#   #
#####

#####
#   #
#####
#    
#    

#####
#   #
#   #
#  ##
#####

#####
#   #
#####
# #  
#   #

#####
#    
#####
    #
#####

#####
  #  
  #  
  #  
  #  

#   #
#   #
#   #
#   #
#####

#   #
#   #
#   #
#   #
  #  

#   #
#   #
#   #
#####
#####

#   #
#   #
  #  
#   #
#   #

#   #
#   #
#####
  #  
  #  

#####
    #
#####
#    
#####


=========================================

0: #####
1: #   #
2: #
3:   #
4:     #
5: # #
6: #  ##
7: ####
8: 

A = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
B = [7, 1, 0, 1, 7]
C = [0, 2, 2, 2, 0]
D = [7, 1, 1, 1, 7]
E = [0, 2, 0, 2 ,0]
F = [0, 2, 0, 2, 2]
G = [0, 2, 0, 1, 0]
H = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
I = [0, 3, 3, 3, 0]
J = [0, 4, 4, 4, 0]
K = [1, 1, 5, 5, 1]
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 0]
M = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
N = [1, 1, 1, 6, 1]
O = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
P = [0, 1, 0, 2, 2]
Q = [0, 1, 1, 6, 0]
R = [0, 1, 0, 5, 1]
S = [0, 2, 0, 4, 0]
T = [0, 3, 3, 3, 3]
U = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
V = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
W = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
X = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
Y = [1, 1, 0, 3, 3]
Z = [0, 4, 0, 2, 0]
```

To further assist compression, I decided to only use number signs (#) to form letters, resulting in better compression. Another great thing about this approach is that it allows me to do a very simple reflection logic, since I'm not required to transform "\" to "/". The resulting font is exceptionally ugly, but as long as it compresses well, I really don't mind about its looks.

In the end, I managed to represent every single letter of the alphabet by using eight different patterns in total (plus one additional dummy pattern for spaces). It was in my best interest to use no more than 10 different patterns (or else I'd have to pay the price of requiring two characters to write down some numbers in the code). I then serialized all letter information in an array, added a little bit of letter selection/concatenation logic, and voilà.

Comment: Would using `#` work better?

Comment: Yes, `#` looks much nicer than `-`. Edited, thanks!